# Dect android phone read incoming number

Tags: android

i have a `DECT` android phone that works on a `analogical` another line. Even it's android it works on a different line because of `DECT`.

***P.S:  Normal reading way don't work !***

So how can i read incoming phone numbers from that phone ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: no i didn't can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add this permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

then you need create a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
public class PhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override  
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();  

            if (extras != null) {  
                String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);  
                Log.d("PhoneReceiver", state);  

                if (extras.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {  
                    String phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                    Log.d("PhoneReceiver", phoneNumber);  
                }  
            }  
        }
    }
```

then you should register this class inside `AndroidManifest` file :

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```